# What's the difference between "should've wrote" and "should've written"?

Tags: differences, should

I've heard an American guy say "should've wrote", but as I far as I know, 
there is supposed to be a past participle (like "written") after "have".

Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: It's contrary to standard grammar, but functionally the same as "should've written." (Should have written.)

Comment: Max, not everybody speaks good English.

Comment: ... or knows  the basics of conjugation and use of the base forms.

Comment: In some dialects the past participle and preterit forms have merged.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to colloquial (informal) speech; not all formal language rules apply there.

I'm sure the guy meant the same thing as "should've written".

Comment: This should be posted as a comment.

Comment: The answer is that in colloquial speech the rules are a bit bent, and not the same ones as taught in language class.

The OP is asking for an explanation about a native speaker saying something ungrammatical.

Comment: It is **not** ungrammatical, nor is it a question of "colloquial", per se. It is dialect. That form is perfectly grammatical _in the particular dialect of English which that person speaks_.

Comment: Would a person *write* 

"I should've wrote a different comment instead."

instead of

"I should've **written** a different comment instead."

?

Answer (score 2):

*Written* is the past participle of *write* in standard varieties of English. Some other varieties use *wrote* or *writ*.

This is not a question of "colloquial" - my own colloquial English happens to have *written*. It is a question of dialect (or variety).